# Xamarin android C# grpc client is unable to create channel

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, grpc

I am using gprc in net471 wpf application, which is working fine. I want to use the same to communicate with xamarin android application.
So kept proto files in a common project (portable class library using netstandard2.0) to refer same proto & generated classes in both WPF & android project.
Hosting the server from net471 project and trying to create a client in xamarin android project, able to implement and build everything. But when trying to run android app and create grpc client using Grpc.Core.Channel getting following error:

{System.DllNotFoundException: grpc_csharp_ext assembly: type: member:(null)  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods+DllImportsFromSharedLib.grpcsharp_redirect_log(Grpc.Core.Internal.GprLogDelegate)  at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeLogRedirector.Redirect (Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods native) [0x00028] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\NativeLogRedirector.cs:49   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor () [0x00011] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\NativeExtension.cs:44   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get () [0x00022] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\NativeExtension.cs:65   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods.Get () [0x00000] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\NativeMethods.cs:49   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit () [0x00016] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\GrpcEnvironment.cs:373   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor () [0x0001e] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\GrpcEnvironment.cs:302   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef () [0x00028] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\GrpcEnvironment.cs:78   at Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor (System.String target, Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials credentials, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] options) [0x00041] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Channel.cs:70   at Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor (System.String target, Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials credentials) [0x00000] in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Channel.cs:55   at aiVRR.MobileApp.Android.Helpers.ServiceClient.Connect () [0x00002] in C:\ActiveDev\Act\RecordingSystems\VideoRecorder\aiVRR.Mobile\aiVRR.MobileApp.Android\Helpers\ServiceClient.cs:78 }

I have also tried to copy grpc_cshar_ext.dll this to ..\obj\Debug\90\android by post build event but still getting the same error. Any clue?

Comment: grpc C# uses the grpc_csharp_ext native library internally and it looks like the native library is not available for your platform? (If you want to run on android, grpc_csharp_ext.dll is certainly not the right version as that's a native library for windows). Note that gRPC C# support on Unity and Xamarin (the only 2 mobile platforms supported) is experimental and it might not work 100%.

Comment: Thanks Jan! , is there a way to confirm about the support? If it is not supported I will not waste time in it and try to work on other options.

Comment: did you find any result?